# Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel" works in IE and firefox but not in Safari

Tags: http, asp-classic

I have got an asp file with the following header Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel" ,it displays the file in an excel format.This works in IE and firefox but not in safari. Any ideas why?

Comment: IE AND Safari AND NOT Firefox, or IE AND Firefox AND NOT Safari?

Comment: @Rodrigo my apologies, it works in IE and firefox but not in Safari

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you can try forcing it like so:

`Content-type: application/force-download`

`Content-disposition: attachment; filename="somefile.txt"`

Please say if it works for you. Hope it helps.

Comment: your code pointed me to the right direction,thanks a lot.the code Response.AddHeader "content-disposition","attachment; filename=filename.xls" worked