# Can I download an Excel file made from a memory stream off an ASP.NET page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, epplus

I have an ASP.NET page where a user provides an ID, and then we pull some data from the DB and put it into an Excel spreadsheet. I would like to create the Excel file in memory and then allow the user to download the file. I could create a file on the server, and then delete it afterwards, but it seems unnecessary. Depending on error handling I could potentially orphan a file with that approach, etc.

Is something like this possible? Or do I need to use a file stream?

On a side note, I'm using [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) as an API (quick plug for it).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want to specify the `Content-Type` and `Content-Dispisition` headers like so - [Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel" works in IE and firefox but not in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959732/response-contenttype-application-vnd-ms-excel-works-in-ie-and-firefox-but-no), then stream your file.  Once complete, call `Response.End()` to stop the application execution.

Code Sample:

```cs
void StreamExcelFile(byte[] bytes)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "application/force-download";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=name_your_file.xls");
    Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
    Response.End();
}
```

Comment: Hi... If I make an ajax call to a web api that returns a memory stream that is of an excel how can I download it in the browser itself?

Answer (score 3):

```
ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage();
.....
.....
.....

byte[] bfr = pck.GetAsByteArray();
Response.ContentType = "application/application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=ExcelFileName.xlsx");

Response.OutputStream.Write(bfr, 0, bfr.Length);
Response.Flush();
Response.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes,  look into using an HTTP Handler to stream the file to the browser from memory.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972953.aspx

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called a generic handler:

http://www.dotnetperls.com/ashx

In a nutshell, what you need to do is define the context type.  Which in your case will be a xls or xlsx.  Set the response, and direct the user to the handler.

They will be prompted to download the file.